# PHP - How to serialize data with special characters from database?

Tags: php, database, serialization

i have a string with special characters, like:

```
$text = "NÃO";
```

When i use serialize($text), returns

```
a:1:{i:0;s:4:"NÃƒO";}
```

but when i use a string that i get from my database, like:

```
$query = SELECT special_text FROM ...
(...)
$text = $row->"special_text"
serialize($text);
```

returns

```
a:1:{i:0;s:3:"NÃO";}
```

, what is crashing my script.

what i have to do when i serialize data from database?
Thx, and sorry for my english

Comment: Don't serialize it. Set the character encoding of the database and the database connection to utf-8 and forget about encoding problems.

Comment: Problem is that i have to serialize my data, i'm importing from a database that is not serialized to a database that needs serialized data to work. So i need to get a array from a old database, serialize, and then insert in the new database, got it? unfortunately i cant change the structure of the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use utf-8, try to encode serialized string before saving it to db, and decode after retrieve it. You may use base64 encoding, just if you use any 8-bit encoding in your db. This method increases data size by 4/3. Or you may use binary (BLOB) field in your db and encode your data with gzip or something like that. Very useful for large amount of text, but increases CPU load.

Comment: I cant change the way of the data is unserialized, so i am unable to decode the data. I cant understand why a string "NÃO" returns 4 positions but the same string from my database returns only 3.